# PHP - nonrecursive deletion of all files and folders in a specified folder

Tags: php

I was using this php code to delete all files in a specified folder:

```
array_map('unlink', glob($path));
```

Now the structure has changed - folders were added (containing files and other folders) and this code doesn't work on them. Is there a nonrecursive solution to delete everything from a specified folder (but not the folder itself)?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to target the files only by filtering them with `is_file`:

```
array_map('unlink', array_filter(glob($path), 'is_file'));
```

EDIT: perhaps in order not to delete the folder itself, you need to skip `.` and `..` - just filter them out.

Comment: But how to delete the folders and their files? (nonrecursive)